# Do I need to declare "Role" class in symfony2 as array or arrayCollection?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this scenario:

- `User` will belongs to `Groups`
- `Groups` will have certain `Roles`

Now I want to know that does I need to declare this in Group.php

This is [Group.php](http://pastebin.com/B6CTa2vM) and this is [Role.php](http://pastebin.com/rrZa8Ejv).

```
$this->roles = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
```

or

```
$this->roles = new array();
```

I am confused how does that work with symfony security. I mean what format symfony security wants roles in arraycollection or array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony 2 expects and `array` of `Role` as returning value in `getRoles()` method. Since a `User` can have many `Group` and each group may have many `Role`, i would do:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User
{
    /* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="users") */
    private $groups;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->groups = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        $roles = array();

        foreach($this->groups as $group) :
            $roles = array_merge($roles, $group->getRoles()->toArray());
        endforeach;

        return $roles;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, your question is `Array` or `ArrayCollection`?

Use ArrayCollection as it does a better job in the context of an ORM and is a lot easier to extend/manipulate (see: [Doctrine Collections](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#collections)).

For more information on setting up collections in Doctrine, see [Initializing Collections](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#initializing-collections)
in the docs.

---

**FOSUserBundle**

You may also want to consider using the excellent [Friends of Symfony (FOS)UserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle). This has full support for `Groups` and `Roles`.

**Access Control Lists (ACLs)**

You may also want to check out ACLs:

> In complex applications, you will often face the problem that access decisions cannot only be based on the person (Token) who is requesting access, but also involve a domain object that access is being requested for. This is where the ACL system comes in.

[Symfony2 - Access Control Lists](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html)